# Emberjs Autocomplete updates another one

Tags: validation, autocomplete, ember.js, nested

I have 2 autocomplete fields and need to update the second autocomplete list from the first selection.  This is what I have.

Using JQuery.mixin and a Validation.mixin for input boxes.

```
Ng.CreateInsertblnController = Ember.ObjectController.extend(Ng.Validate,{
content: []
}


Ng.CreateInsertblnView = Ember.View.extend({

 vesselPicker: JQ.AutoComplete.extend({
   source: Ng.vessels.autocomplete,
   minLength: 0
 }),

 voyagePicker: JQ.AutoComplete.extend({     
  // JQ.AutoComplete extends from Ember.TextField
  source: Ng.voyage.autocomplete,
  minLength: 0
 })

});

Ng.vessels = Ember.ObjectController.create({
 inputText: "",
 autocomplete: function(request, response) {
   var term = request.term;
   var self=this;
    $.getJSON( "http://myjsonlink", request, function( data, status, xhr ) {

        var list = [];
        $.each(data,function(id,item){
            list.push(item.code);
        });
        response( list );
    });
}
});

 Ng.voyages = Ember.ObjectController.create({
 inputText: "",
 autocomplete: function(request, response) {
   var term = request.term;
   var self=this;
    $.getJSON( "http://myjsonlink", request, function( data, status, xhr ) {

        var list = [];
        $.each(data,function(id,item){
            list.push(item.code);
        });
        response( list );
    });
}
});
```

I tried creating Ng.vessels and Ng.voyages in the controller, but in the view I'm not able to retrieve controller data.  My question is how can I declare the 2 objects in the controller, how to invoke them from view and how to refresh second autocomplete.   Any help would be much appreciated thanks.